# How to make a surface from 3 curves?

Tags: modeling

I have this 3 curves along a mesh corner and I would like to merge them to make a rounded corner. How can I do it? in this case every curve has the same ammount of vertices, but if tha wasn't the case, how coul I do it?
[image: curves disposition]

thanks in advance

Comment: For smooth surfaces "man made", I would recommend to use *Nurbs Surface(s)* to model these. Because starting from curves to make surfaces is always complex and frustrating, from my point of view. Now, in your picture, it looks like you could use a *Screw* modifier to rotate let say the bottom curve around the green axis by 90°.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Using Blender 3.6.8)*

Following is an example of a *Nurbs Surface* created by rotating 3 times an initial *Nurbs Curve*. Be careful to use the menu entry *Add/Surface* for the curve, not *Add/Curve* !

[image: NURBS Surface]

Resources: [image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I can work with this